# How can I set the pep8 linter to accept 2 space indents?

Tags: python, pep8, sublimelinter

The pep8 default states indents should be multiples of 4.

**What argument can I pass to a pep8 config file so indents with a multiple of 2 are accepted?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging, [From the Docs](http://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html#configuration):

> Example:
>
> `[pep8]
>      ignore = E226,E302,E41
>      max-line-length = 160`
>
> At the project level, a setup.cfg file or a tox.ini file is read if present (.pep8 file is also supported, but it is deprecated). If none of these files have a [pep8] section, no project specific configuration is loaded.
>
> If the ignore option is not in the configuration and not in the arguments, only the error codes E123/E133, E226 and E241/E242 are ignored (see below).

To ignore ONLY the Multiples of 4 rule Use ignore `E111`